# Can you determine the min or max of a list using only the list monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, foldable

Trying to understand the relation between Monad and Foldable. I am aware that that part of the value of the Monad, Applicative and Functor typeclasses is their ability to lift functions over structure, but what if I wanted to generate a summary value (e.g. min or max) for the values contained in a Monad?

This would be impossible without an accumulator right (like in foldable)? And to have an accumulator you have to inject or destroy structure?

```
min :: Ord a => a -> a -> a

foldMin :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => t a -> Maybe a
foldMin t = foldr go Nothing t
  where
    go x Nothing = Just x
    go x (Just y) = Just (min x y)
```

Here, the Nothing value is the accumulator. So it would not be possible to do an operation that produces a summary value like this within the confines of a `do` block?

Comment: `wat :: [a] -> Maybe a; wat xs = do { return (minimum xs) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, so forgive me if this isn't a useful answer, but as I understand it, the core of the question is this:

> So it would not be possible to do an operation that produces a summary value like this within the confines of a `do` block?

Correct, that would not be possible. Haskell's `do` notation is syntactic sugar over `Monad`, so basically syntactic sugar over `>>=` and `return`.

`return`, as you know, doesn't let you 'access' the contents of the `Monad`, so the only access to the contents you have is via `>>=`, and in the case of the list monad, for instance, that only gives you one value at a time.

Notice that `Foldable` doesn't even require that the data container is a `Functor` (much less a `Monad`). Famously, [Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Set.html) isn't a `Functor` instance, but it *is* a `Foldable` instance.

You can, for example, find the minimum value in a set:

```
Prelude Data.Foldable Set> foldr (\x -> Just . maybe x (min x)) Nothing $ Set.fromList [42, 1337, 90125, 2112]
Just 42
```

Answer (score 3):

The contrived and inefficient code below is the closest I can get to "using only the list monad". This is probably not what the OP is looking for, but here it is.

I also exploit `head` (which you can replace with `listToMaybe`, if we want totality), and `null`. I also use `empty` (which you can replace with `[]`).

The code works by non deterministically picking an element `m` and then checking that no greater elements exist. This has a quadratic complexity.

```
import Control.Applicative

maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maximum xs = head maxima
   where
   isMax m = null $ do
      x <- xs
      if x > m
         then return x
         else empty
   maxima = do
      m <- xs   -- non deterministically pick a maximum
      if isMax m
         then return m
         else empty
```

Comment: This is a really cool answer. But yea I meant from a single monadic context (not passing a value into a context), which I now understand is impossible due to the nature of join . fmap

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure, what the actual question ist, but the need for an accumulator can be hidden with a `Monoid` instance. Then - for your minimum example - you can use use `foldMap` from `Data.Foldable` to map and merge all values of your `Foldable`. E.g.:

```
data Min a = Min { getMin :: Maybe a } deriving Show

instance Ord a => Monoid (Min a) where
  mempty                                = Min Nothing
  mappend a (Min Nothing)               = a
  mappend (Min Nothing) b               = b
  mappend (Min (Just a)) (Min (Just b)) = Min (Just (min a b))

foldMin :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => t a -> Maybe a
foldMin = getMin . foldMap (Min . Just)
```